# Appending to an element using the name as the selector

Tags: jquery

I've moved a bunch of code to a .net usercontrol.  In order to keep things fairly generic, I'm trying to change all my jQuery selectors that relied on unique IDs to either a class or name selector.

Right now, I'm having issues appending HTML that I generate with jQuery to a  element using a name selector.

Here's what I'm talking about:

```
var displayResultsName = $(this).data("str");
$(html).appendTo('[name=' + displayResultsName + ']');
```

For some reason, jQuery doesn't like this.  Is there a better, or correct way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: What does jQuery say exactly ? Did you try putting html between quotes ? $("html").appendTo(...)

Comment: Just a quick test, [works](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/MJZm5/1/).

Comment: Which browser you are testing? It works in Chrome. Didn't try in others

Comment: I'm actually trying to append to a <select> list...it worked when I appended to it via the ID, but not the name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing the quotes try this

```
$(html).appendTo('[name="' + displayResultsName + '"]');
```

Comment: But, it works without the quotes in Chrome. Not sure that could solve OP's issue. I would recommend to use quotes anyway

Comment: From [jQuery Attribute selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/): _Attribute values in selector expressions must follow the rules for W3C CSS selectors; in general, that means anything other than a valid identifier should be surrounded by quotation marks._ Quotes are nice to have but not necessarily required

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/U6WGH/

```
//simple value added to selector by name
$('input[name="myInput"]').val('Hello!');

//object created in memory and appended to div by name
var domObject = $('<span>Yo.</span>');
$('div[name="myDiv"]').append(domObject);

//object created on the fly and appended to div by name
$('<span>Wasup?</span>').appendTo($('div[name="otherDiv"]'));
```